# Movie about a guy travelling to a UFO landing place

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for an American movie (probably '90s-early '00s) about a man, who travelling through a desert heading toward (?) a UFO landing place. Movie begins in the city, during the night.

One scene I remember, is when the protagonist spoke with a man in a motel, who claimed to drill a hole in his forehead in order to open his "third eye".

Movie was bit surreal, on the edge of fantasy. It's definitely not "*Interstate 60*" nor "*Wristcutters*".

Thanks for help and sorry for bad english!

Comment: Off to a good start, but we could use some more details, if you haven't already, can I suggest you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can edit in any more details.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for a strange independent film called [Lift](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119538/) from 1997.

> Young pizza delivery man Larry wanders through the desert waiting for the aliens to land - he believes in everything he hears and does anything anyone tells him.

One of the people he meets along the way is some weird evangelist who **invites him to his motel room, rambles on about trepanation and then proceeds to drill a hole in his own head to open his "third eye".** The movie is currently [available on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dn_-Mus2puo).

Here's the poster (from rottentomatoes):

[image]